# How to add 2D real time dynamic text to a Three.js scene?

Tags: javascript, text, three.js, 2d

I need a better solution to add 2d text to my three.js scene. I've tried using TextGeometry but I can't update the text in real-time (in a way that won't hurt performance) and I don't want to have to draw triangles. 
Does anyone know of any libraries or alternative solutions to add 2d text to a scene? I need to be able to easily update the text in realtime. If you know of a library I would greatly appreciate it if you could provide a code example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `CanvasTexture`, which supports updateable canvases as sources.

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 128;
canvas.height = 128;
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var texture = new THREE.CanvasTexture(canvas);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

let i = 0;
setInterval(() => {
  ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 128, 128);
  ctx.fillStyle = "black";
  ctx.font = "80px sans-serif";
  ctx.fillText(i, 50, 90);
  texture.needsUpdate = true;
  i++;
}, 1000);
```

See this pen for the whole thing: https://codepen.io/dawken/pen/YzydEza?editors=1000

You could use a camera-facing plane instead of a cube to make it look 2D.

Answer (score 1):

I did some more research and found this [library](https://github.com/vasturiano/three-spritetext). I was able to integrate it into my project with no problems. It works exactly as I need it to.

Answer (score 0):

If you are use webgl(webgl2) context, you must create new canvas, write you're text there (in 2d context) and then turn you canvas to img, and use this img, this is a best solution and all frameworks use it